# How to retrieve a BluetoothDevice object from Bluetooth Settings in Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have an app that opens Bluetooth Settings on my phone. What I want is, after I have paired with & connected to a device from the Bluetooth Settings, I want to come back to my app & retrieve the Bluetooth device so that I can check the distance between my phone & the connected Bluetooth device using my app. How do I retrieve that BluetoothDevice object from Settings??

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to discover bluetooth devices in your app using a bluetooth adapter. List the devices, and let the user connect to it in your app! Then you have a device instance you can communicate with.

Here is a tutorial from google

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Problem with my app is, it doesn't always discover all the nearby bluetooth devices even though they're perfectly in range. However, when I search for any Bluetooth device from Setting, all of them show up at all times. Hence I was wondering if there was any way I could pass that paired object to my app without actually making my app perform the search.